# 301 redirect not working in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two domains, `autodromodifranciacorta.it` and `franciacortacircuit.com` both pointing to the same website hosted on this IP address: `94.23.64.40`.

Now i want all the content to be under one single domain, so i decided to 301 redirect all the traffic from `franciacortacircuit.com` to `autodromodifranciacorta.it`

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Entire Site to New Domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^franciacortacircuit\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.autodromodifranciacorta\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://autodromodifranciacorta.it/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The redirect is not working and i have no clue why, because the syntax looks correct to me.
The .htaccess file is processed, because if i put a typo in it, i get server error.

Wha'ts wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your second http_host  condition is wrong and it never matches if the current host is franciacortacircuit.com, You need to use an **OR** condition to match against 2 diffrent hosts.

```
 #Redirect Entire Site to New Domain
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^franciacortacircuit\.com$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.autodromodifranciacorta\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://autodromodifranciacorta.it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not working... i get this: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, postmaster@autodromodifranciacorta.it and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log. (If you try now you will see it working because i temporarily put a PHP 301 redirect. But i just tested your config and it's not working :(  )

Comment: @Alberto fontana - I posted a solution that would work, but it was deleted by a Moderator so I cannot post it again. sorry.

Comment: damn...why was it deleted?